# Gatsby page hosted on S3 with Cloudfront. How to deploy after Gatsby Cloud discontinuation?

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, netlify

I have a Gatsby static page hosted on AWS S3 with Cloudfront. I used to build the page on Gatsby Cloud after which it would be deployed to s3. My life was easy.

Now that Gatsby Cloud is no more, is it possible to build on Netlify and automatically deploy to S3? Or is there another platform that can build Gatsby sites and have integrations with S3?